# Map HTC Logo on HTC One

Tags: buttons, htc-one

Is there any way to have the HTC Logo on the HTC One (between the home and back buttons) to be used as a multitasking button AND press and hold for a menu button?

Answer (score 0):

There are custom kernels supporting the HTC logo as a button. You might e.g. want to check [tbaldens kernel @ XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2244620), which is available in different variants underlying the logo with different features:

- HOME2Wake and HTCLogo2Sleep
- HOME2Wake and HTCLogoMenu

Watch the videos over at XDA-Developers to see how it works. It is not the combination you asked for, but maybe that one was added later as a variant (another dev continued with a fork in [this second thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2255160), which lists a few more details), or you can ask the dev to do so.

Comment: I have already looked at those, neither of which serve my purposes

Comment: To my knowledge, at this time there don't exist other solutions. Which does of course not mean it won't ever be: I'm pretty sure more solutions will pop up with the time.